# How to call a SQL Scalar function using Apache DbUtils

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, user-defined-functions, apache-commons-dbutils

I am trying to call a `SQLServer` stored Scalar function through `Apache Common DbUtils`.
I tried something like this:

`run.query("SELECT [MyDB].[dbo].[test] ('testParam')",  new ScalarHandler());`

But, I get this exception:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to identify the table SELECT [MyDB].[dbo].[test] ('testParam') for the metadata.`

While, running the same query in the SQLServer returns a valid Scalar value.

I am wondering how can I call a Scalar function using Apache DbUtils.

UPDATE: For Table-valued functions it works if I ues "`SELECT * FROM`..."

Comment: Have you tried with the exec command instead of select? http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188332.aspx

Comment: Yes, EXEC doesn't return anything.

Comment: I don't have experience with Apache Common DBUtils, but I would try to execute the code as I'd have a recordset with one row and one column.

Comment: run is the instance of QueryRunner? It has argument pmdKnownBroken in constructor. Try to set it to true.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ResultSet parameter in ScalarHandler?

Comment: @Dd2, What I mentioned in the UPDATE of my question to use a Table-valud function, which has recordset/resultset, is your solution. However, I want to know if we can call a scalar-valued table through DbUtils

Comment: @WadimX, yes it is QuerryRunner, and it works with your solution. Would you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that there is a bug in Apache Common DbUtils (v. 1.5) `AbstractQueryRunner` (base class of `QueryBuilder`) code. It has parameter `pmdKnownBroken`, which desribed as follows:

if `pmdKnownBroken` is set to true, we won't even try it; if false, we'll try it, and if it breaks, we'll remember not to use it again.

But does not work as described, because[`fillStatement`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/dbutils/AbstractQueryRunner.html#line.189)method does not catch an exception when calling `java.sql.getParameterMetaData`.

So you should **set pmdKnownBroken to true**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to run a SQL Server scalar function with DBUtils, try by this way

```
Object[] params = {"inputparam"};
ScalarHandler<T> scalar = new ScalarHandler<T>();
run.query("{CALL DB.dbo.test(?)}", scalar, params);
```

If you don't find a solution with DBUtils yo can use a CallableStatement

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://....";
SQLServerDataSource sqls = new SQLServerDataSource();
sqls.setURL(url);
sqls.getConnection();

CallableStatement callStatement = sqls.getConnection().prepareCall("{? = CALL DB.dbo.f_promedio(?,?)}");
callStatement.setDouble(2, 1.8);
callStatement.setDouble(3, 6.8);
callStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);
callStatement.execute();

double d = callStatement.getDouble(1);
```

Comment: It throws the same exception with CALL. And the second solution is not the answer of this question.

Comment: First solution does not return any resultset for me calling the function but not raise the same exception, check the call syntax.

Comment: Maybe, because you passed true as a parameter when creating the run object. With that it works.

Comment: I asked you about this parameter in comment to your question. Does it solve the problem?